# java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I am trying to append or add a trusted.certs file onto a machine and every machine I go to I get the error:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

When running the command below. I don't understand how it has been tampered with even on a fresh machine? Is there a way around this error?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore -srckeystore ".\trusted.certs" -destkeystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs" -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit
```

Comment: passwords incorrect?

Comment: Hazarding a massive guess here: your keystore was tampered with or the password is incorrect. Just a hunch though.

Comment: Ya but this is a fresh machine?? no one has been tampering with anything? So I am confused how the password could be incorrect?